# Encoding a java string with UTF char \&\#232

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I have Strings which contains strange UTF chars... how can I deal with that?

for instance è = \&#232  ...

so I have

```
String str = "Pel\&\#232" ;
String correct str2 =??? ; // i'd like to have "Pelè"
```

then I have loads of this strange chars and I really don't know how to deal with that...

Another example : "J. Ho\&#345;ej\&#353;"

Can someone help?

---

thank you very much for your answer.
I'm reading a big text file, downloaded from a website that I cannot change.
In the file itself the name of person is saved like that. Is not the encoding of the file.
Nor I can do it manually because I have 300 names with this problem.

another example :

in the text file the name of the person is "Constantin S\&#226;rbu" that should be Sîrbu

I'm stuck

EDIT*** I solved creating a manual function to relate the HTML value to the unicode... Took me a while but it works.

Comment: Please fix your encoding. :-)

Comment: Do the ``\``s appear in the actual code, or are they just there to prevent the site from rendering `è` instead of `\&#232`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just put the è in the string itself. Something like:
`String s = "Pelè";`

Answer (score 1):

A Java Unicode character looks like `\uXXXX`  The XXXX are exactly four hex digits and no terminating ; or whatever is needed.

Java needs its Unicode in hexadecimal but your 232 is base 10.  Also Java always requires four hex digits.  Since 232 denary equals E8 hex, that gives you è = `\u00E8` in a Java string:

```
System.out.println("Pel\u00E8 was a great footballer.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the encoding of your source files to UTF-8 (this should be done in the preferences of your editor). Then simply use `String str = "Pelè"`.

Comment: More precisely, set the editor encoding to your platform default encoding (often this is UTF-8, but not always), or to what you pass the compiler with `-encoding`.

Answer (score 0):

You say you cannot change the input file, but what about generating an intermediate file with the text you want?

```
perl -pe 's/\\&#(\d+)/ sprintf("\\u%04X", $1) /ge' inputfile >intermediate
```